# How can I send a body in a HTTP request using Apache http client's URIBuilder?

Tags: java, http, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I know I can add http parameters using the `setParameter` method, but how do I pass a body to the http request using the `URIBuilder` class?

For example, this

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder().setScheme("http")
                .setHost("localhost:9091/test").setParameter("a", "1")
                .setParameter("b", "2").build();
```

is equivalent to the following curl request:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:9091/test\?a\=1\&b\=2`

but how do I build a URL using `URIBuilder` (or any other class) for the following curl:

`curl -X POST http://localhost:9091/test -d '{"a":1,"b":2}'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.create("POST")
    .setUri("http://localhost:9091/test")
    .setEntity(new StringEntity("{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .build();
```